# opencart - I am trying to list weightunit in featured products and products list in category.tpl

Tags: opencart

I am trying to list weightunit in featured and products list in category.tpl and running into issues. Anyone know how to achieve selecting and displaying weightunit in featured.tpl and category.tpl. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First create a method to you category method so that you can get all weight units.

```
public function getWeightClasses() {
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class wc LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd ON (wc.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id) WHERE wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
  return $query->rows;
}
```

Now call this from your category controller

```
$this->load->model('catalog/category');
$data['weightUnits'] = $this->model_catalog_category->getWeightClasses();
print_r($data['weightUnits']); // all weight units
```

Comment: you are welcome. if it is working, please accept the answer with a up vote so that people can benefit.

Comment: i spoke to soon. I had it working fine for some hours and then i added one style element to category.tpl and the product category page does not open. Freezes while trying to open. I added the following code ' public function getWeightClasses() {
  $tablewithunit = $this->db->query("SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class wc LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd ON (wc.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id) WHERE wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
  return $tablewithunit->row['unit'];
 }
' to model/catalog/category.

Comment: am not able to format my code while posting for some reason. so i will add it how ever i can until i figure out how to format it like yours.

Comment: this code in category and features controller. $this->load->model('catalog/category');
$data['weightunit'] = $this->model_catalog_category->getWeightClasses();

Comment: one style element as i mentioned in category.tpl at following code which i removed to make work again, although it malfunctioned the code above. <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <div class="product-layout product-list col-xs-12">
          <div class="product-thumb">

Comment: this code is used to display the weighunit <?php echo ' / ' . $weightunit; ?> which i include in category.tpl and featured.tpl. it still works in featured although freezes category.

Comment: i take it all back. it works fine now. i removed the following line $this->load->model('catalog/category'); as it was already called earlier in the code and everything is working again.